# Bitcoin URL scheme

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, standard, bip21-uri

What is the URL scheme that is used by Bitcoin to copy transaction information directly into the client? Which versions of Bitcoin clients support it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Bitcoin Improvement Proposal that defines the Bitcoin URI scheme is  [BIP21](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0021).

The simple syntax is:

```
bitcoin:<address>[?amount=<amount>][?label=<label>][?message=<message>]
```

On the desktop all of Armory, Electrum and MultiBit respond to Bitcoin URI clicks in a browser and I believe Bitcoin-QT V0.7 does as well.

On mobiles Android Bitcoin Wallet does. On the iPhone the blockchain.info app does.

Comment: Bitcoin-Qt v0.7 for Windows does.  Not Mac or Linux yet.

Comment: It's important to note that although it isn't specified in the simple syntax, '?' after the first are changed to '&' as in regular URLs.  For example: `bitcoin:<myaddress>?amount=1&message=mymsg`

Comment: Not to nitpick, but the acronym "BIP" stands for *Bitcoin Improvement Proposal* instead of *Bitcoin Improvement Process*.

Comment: Apparently the number of decimals in the BTC amount matters. My wallet was rejecting the uri until I reduced the decimals to eight.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

```
<a rel="payment" href="bitcoin:bitcoin_address_is_here?amount=5.00?message=payment to site name"><h2>Pay in Bitcoin now</h2></a>
```