# Is it possible to create a Bitcoin URI with multiple outputs?

Tags: payment, bip21-uri

The [Bitcoin URI scheme](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/bitcoin-url-scheme) allows for the creation of single-click payment request, using the format

```
bitcoin:<address>&amount=<amount>
```

such as

```
bitcoin:1AzGoMQfrQ7fYaE12dAvEVkke8111rxwCm&amount=0.01
```

Does the URI scheme also allow multiple payments to multiple destination addresses?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible according to [BIP 0021](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki). The BNF grammar for the `bitcoin:` URI scheme starts with:

> ```
> bitcoinurn     = "bitcoin:" bitcoinaddress [ "?" bitcoinparams ]
> ```

Since `bitcoinparams` has no address information, this means that exactly *one* output address is required.